# How to use facebook mobile hosting api to create app link in facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've preferred the below link to create a link object and app link but unfortunately i could not able to find anything from this link
[Mobile Hosting Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api). So please guys can you please tell me the exact steps to create the app link for my mobile application.
Here is the manifest code for the activity

```
<activity android:name=".AppLinkActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.GoCarDev" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and here is the Activity on which i have to redirect the app link

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    Uri targetUrl =
            AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Link" + targetUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());

    } else {
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
                this,
                new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                        //process applink data
                    }
                });
    }
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Firstly you need to create an app link for your app using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks. The user when click the link with your app being installed in his phone. You will receive a call back to onNewIntent() (override this function first) where you can get the link using `AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());`

Comment: thank you Babar for your solution but i've already created app link using your above link but it redirects me to playstore.

Comment: did you added this "com.GoCarDev" as scheme when creating the app link?